# Update TCP load balancing to HTTP(S) load balancing on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer

I use kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Plataform and I want to change my load balancer from "TCP load balancing" to "HTTP(S) load balancing" (layer 7).

Currently the configuration about "TCP load balancing" is:

[image]

For deploy NGINX and create automatically the load balancer, I use the ingress-nginx chart (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). I've been checking the documentation and haven't found the config for change load balancer layer.

I'm a beginner in GCP load balancer. Can anyone help with getting started? Please, if more information is needed, I will provide it.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue, do you managed to solve it please? 
Does the solution proposed by @BakulMitra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch the way you’re load balancing. We don't change the load balancer type from the GCP UI.  So you should create new gke resources. As per your case you would have to use an ingress resource to have external https load balancing.

Check the following [Document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#:%7E:text=In%20a%20GKE%20cluster%2C%20you%20create%20and%20configure%20an%20HTTP%28S%29%20load%20balancer%20by%20creating%20a%20Kubernetes%20Ingress%20object.%20An%20Ingress%20object%20must%20be%20associated%20with%20one%20or%20more%20Service%20objects%2C%20each%20of%20which%20is%20associated%20with%20a%20set%20of%20Pods) for more information.

Comment: thanks. I'll check in more detail.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit lost, could you please guide me on what to look for in the document and how to solve it?

Comment: I have posted new question on this topic about solution with NEGs at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950423/gcp-external-http-cloud-load-balancer-with-nginx-ingress-on-gke . What do you think about this solution @roliveira ?